# How would you simulate Brownian motion with a die?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, monte-carlo

You can simulate Brownian motion on $[0, 1]$ for instance by splitting it into $K$ intervals and at each time $k \Delta t$ add $N(0, \Delta t)$ to your running total, where $\Delta t = 1/K$.

If you only have a fair coin and can't sample from $N(0, \Delta t)$ you can instead flip the coin and add $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ if heads, $-\sqrt{\Delta t}$ if tails.

In some rigorous sense this approximation converges to Brownian motion.

My question is if instead of a fair coin you have a die, how would you use it to sample from $N(0, \Delta t)$?

I thought of using a discrete version of the probability integral transform, but that doesn't seem to give the right variance.

Edit: the kind of solution I'm looking for would be to find the "best" vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to map the die's outcomes with.

For $n=2$ (the two-sided die) the solution is $v = [-\sqrt{\Delta t}, \sqrt{\Delta t}]'$.

For $n=3$, it seems like $v = [-\sqrt{(3/2) \Delta t}, 0, \sqrt{(3/2) \Delta t} ]'$ is the right pick: it's symmetric and has the right variance.

For $n=4$, we can use the tetrahedron as two coins (like a binomial tree) and get the vector
$v = [-\sqrt{2 \Delta t}, 0, 0, \sqrt{2 \Delta t}]'$. There are many other vectors that have the same variance and are symmetric, for example $[- \sqrt{\Delta t}, -\sqrt{\Delta t}, \sqrt{\Delta t}, \sqrt{\Delta t}]'$. This is what we get if we take the parity of the outcome.

Arguably both these vectors are "suboptimal" in the sense that it intuitively makes sense that there should be one value from each quartile.

I guess the question is, what am I trying to optimise?

Comment: You can still simulate a fair coin using a die: for example, tails if the result is even, heads otherwise.

Comment: @Dark: thank you, I'm aware of this, but I'm looking for something cleverer

Comment: Something that doesn't throw away most of the randomness in the die

Comment: You could throw the die N times with N sufficiently large to sample from an continuous uniform r.v.

Comment: @krey please disregard if I am understanding this wrongly... How about this? take the Möbius function of the number $n$ you get on the dice. $\mu(n)$, for $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ it is $\{1,-1,-1,0,-1,1\}$. For instance if $\mu(n) \in \{1,0\}$ then make it equivalent to $0$ in other case $1$.  Probably this is basically the same as Dark said, so sorry if it does not provide you a proper clue! good luck.

Comment: @krey Another idea just in case regarding your comment "Something that doesn't throw away most of the randomness in the die": you can use the Möbius sequence, https://oeis.org/A008683 , as follows: throw the dice, you got $n$ and starting in the first element of the sequence, jump $n$ elements right into the sequence, and take that value and convert it to $0$ or $1$ as above,then throw again the dice and jump again to the right in the sequence,etc. As the Möbius sequence has pseudorandom properties, you would obtain a Brownian motion - like sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Answer (score 1):

If X represents the outcome of the roll of a fair die, the X is a random variable with mean (7/2) and standard deviation $\sqrt{(35/12)}$.

$(X-7/2)\sqrt{(12/35)}$ then gives you a random variable with mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

For a large number of rolls  $\sum (X_i-7/2)\sqrt{(12/35)\Delta t}$ is approximately a standard normal random variable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In the language of the second half of the question, this explains that it's possible to use a $v$ with equally spaced components.

Comment: You can use pretty much and random process and make it work.